# Adding a custom page in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

How can i add a custom page where i have a grid shows some records(content). and some other graphical representation e.g. graphs ? Please eleborate in detail. Can i have pages created in module and have linked to front website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to do it is creating a custom controller which will display the web page (rather than page as content item). There is an example here http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Building-a-hello-world-module

Of course you can modify the Page content item to add your custom content, but I think that in your case it's better to do a custom controller.

If you want something more specific, ask another question. You're asking too much in one question :)